# Attach eventListener resize from different js files

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

What's the correct way of attaching different resize events to the window?
I'm thinking about adding two seperate js files which both add an eventListener to window.onresize.

```
//1.js:
let function1 = function(){...};
window.addEventListener('resize', function1);

//2.js
let function2 = function(){...};
window.addEventListener('resize', function2);
```

Wouldn't they overwrite each other, or is this the way to go?

Comment: They won't overwrite each other. They'll be queued in the order they are interpreted in your files.

Comment: Did you not test it to see if they overwrote each other? seems like it would have been simple to test.

Comment: Test it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/62hvLqgb/5/

Comment: @epascarello yes, I wanted to know if this is good practice. Thanks!